# In vue3, is it a bad idea to use the Lifecycle injection API outside of the setup when using the Options API? What would be a good alternative if so?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component, lifecycle, vue-options-api

Here's my what I'm trying to do:

When my component is mounted, I'm binding events globally on the window with a custom `WindowEvents` service (such as `keydown` to capture global shortcuts without having to be focused on the component) and when that specific component is unmounted, those events will automatically unbind themselves.

Here's how I'm actually doing it:

```
// MyComponent.vue
{
  mounted() {
    WindowEvents.bind({
      keydown: (e) => {
        // Keys is a custom service to compare keycodes
        if(Keys.check(e.which, "ESCAPE", "ENTER", "RETURN"))
          this.submit()
      }
    })
  },
  methods: {
    submit() {
      // will save data and remove this component
    }
  }
}
```

Whenever `MyComponent` is on screen, focused or not, and the user presses either escape or enter, it will call the submit function of `MyComponent`.

I want that `keydown` event to be deactivated when the instance of `MyComponent` is unmounted. right now I'm achieving this by using the `onUnmounted` lifecycle hook inside the `WindowEvents` `bind` method:

```
import { onUnmounted } from "vue"

class WindowEvents {
  static register(events, target) {
    return new this({ events, target })
  }

  static bind(events, target) {
    const e = this.register(events, target).bind()

    // !! HERE !!
    onUnmounted(() => e.unbind())
    return e
  }


  constructor(options) {
    ...
  }

  bind() { /* bind events */ }
  unbind() { /* unbind events */ }

}
```

***THIS ALL WORKS PERFECTLY***

I'm just wondering if this is a bad practice that the vue devs might patch out or "fix" later since I could not find any example in the docs using these lifecycle hooks outside of the component's `setup()` or the Composition API. If I did do it in the `setup()`, I wouldn't have access to my component's `props` or `methods` such as `this.close()` used in the `keydown` event in my example, unless I also set those up in the `setup()`. But at that point, what even is the point of using the Options API.

In case this stops working, I will just remove the `onUnmounted` call in the bind method and just manually unbind them in my component:

```
  // in WindowEvents
  static bind(events, target) {
    return this.register(events, target).bind()
  }
```

```
  // in MyComponent
  mounted() {
    this.events = WindowEvents.bind({ /* keydown */ })
  },
  unmounted() {
    this.events.unbind()
  }
```

Maybe I'm just trying to min-max my code too much